# How to buffer multiple DB insert requests for later delayed bulk execution with mySQL and C#?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a situtation where the application gathers a long list of DB inserts like about one hundered per second from external devices. The application that the receives these requests runs on a different server than the mySQL DB itself.

**Since I do not want to open and close the DB for every single insert I thought it would be a good idea to gather them first in some sort of queue and then insert them alltogether.**

While I was thinking about using the `DataSet mySQL` construct for this I have one problem.

I need to `insert some data into table A with autoincrement key`.

`And this key I then need to use to insert a subsequent record in table B.`

While in normal mySQL I would just use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` for this purpose - but when using DataSet to gather the insert requests I do not know how to do that.

What would be the correct way to solve this?

ps or can I just insert at the time of the requests and don't worry about the fact that the mySQL is runnning on a remote server. So there is no need to gather these requests in the first place for a later bulk insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are speeding about performance issues here, so it is important to look at alternatives. You are looking at storing persistent data. Therefore, the most options might be :-

1. sessions
2. files
3. databases

Sessions are not recommended for operational type data and have limitations regarding size of data that can be stored. I would exclude this option.

Files are generally the slowest thing on your computer, so opening, writing to and appending to a file might not be a most efficient.

That would leave databases. Personally, I would recommend this option over the other 2 I identified. I hear your concern about continuous opening of database connections. PDO has an anwer for this.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', $user, $pass,
               array( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true
       ));
```

Answer (score 0):

for your `LAST_INSERT_ID()`:

```
select max(id) from yourdb.yourtbl;
```

Comment: thanks, but isn't this extremely inefficient? Is the DataSet approch the right one for this problem in the first place?